# Cannot run jar file without installed scilab

Tags: java, scilab

I am new to scilab and java.

I'm working with java+scilab and trying to create a jar file that will run on any computer and will not depend on whether scilab installed or not.

I followed step by step the document [javasci v2](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/compile_and_run_javasci_v2.html) and have a success with running my examples under eclipse.

I use 'File-Export' to create jar file of my project. The jar file can be successfully run on the same computer, but not on the computer where scilab is not installed. I have no idea what could be the reason.

Thanks in advance.

Pavel

P.S. 
OS: Fedora 19, Scilab version: 5.4.1 (32 bit), java sdk version: 7u25 (32 bit)

Comment: try exporting required files along with the jar.

Comment: There are probably some library files, (.so) that need to be included in the jar.